# Erro 404 no deploy

Tags: java, css, bootstrap, spring-boot

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando o spring boot, localmente ele carrega tudo perfeitamente (estou me referindo a arquivos estáticos) mas quando faço deploy no heroku me é retornado o erro 404 para arquivos css. Alguém dá uma idéia de como solucionar esse problema!

Comment: Percebi que a pasta dist (bootstrap baixado através do npm) está sendo ignorada pelo git. Alguém sabe me dizer o porquê?

Comment: Seu problema já foi resolvido?